# How to prevent SQL to store escape character with single quote character

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server

I need to store text strings that will have single quote at beginning and end.
I'm issuing JavaScript command from PHP.
I'm adding the quotes to the string like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'function GetCodes() {';
        echo 'var vlist = document.getElementById("vListOfCodes");';
        echo 'var vcodes = "";';
        echo 'var i;';
        echo 'for (i = 0; i < vlist.length; i++) {';
            echo 'if (i == 0) {';
                echo 'vcodes = vcodes + "\'" + vlist.options[i].value + "\'";';
            echo '}';
            echo 'else {';
                echo 'vcodes = vcodes + ",\'" + vlist.options[i].value + "\'";';
            echo '}';
        echo '}';
        echo 'document.getElementById("vStringOfCodes").value = vcodes;';
    echo '}';
echo '</script>';
```

When the form is posted and the $_POST['vStringOfCodes'] data saved to SQL SERVER table the backslash character is added along with the single quote, meaning instead of a value in the field of

> 'mystring',´mystring2',...

i have

> \'mystring\',\'mystring2\',...

How can i prevent those backslashes from being added there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php native function `stripslashes`.

```
$str = "\'mytext\'";
echo stripslashes($str);
//outputs 'mytext'
//in your case
echo stripslashes($_POST['HiddenInput'])
```

[Php function stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: Thing is, it's javascript inside PHP... How would i pass the javascript var to the php one and back?

Comment: Do you want to exchange variables between php and javascript or do you want to parse the javascript? If the latter send the data within another field from javascript

Comment: Just parse the JavaScript.
For now only solution found is to store like this and use in the SQL Stored Proc
`DECLARE @var2 nvarchar(100) = (SELECT REPLACE(@var1, '\', ''))`

to strip them when i do a
`SELECT...WHERE IN...`

For now it is solving my problem but I'm not sure this is the best solution in the future

Comment: Why don't you use my answer in php? All you need to do is `stripslashes($_POST['HiddenInput'])`

Comment: i was not using it because i was not thinking straight... Once i remove my nose from the screen the picture got clearer ;)

Thanks, tested and working. Can you just adjust your answer to this final one so i can accept it?